# IdentityServer prompt user login

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I would like the user to be redirected to the login page again after an hour but I do not know how to configure that in my server. I Included both `AccessTokenLifetime` and `AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime` on my ID server but this does not have any effect. I am using an angular client and perhaps I would need to change something in my angular config. Below is how my client is configure in the ID server

```
new Client {
    ClientId = "angularClient",
    ClientName = "angular client",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequirePkce = true,
    RequireClientSecret = false,

    RedirectUris = {
        "http://localhost:4401/checkout"
    },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = {
        "http://localhost:4401"
    },

    AllowedScopes = new List < string > {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "role",
        "api1.read"
    },

    // AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
    // AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 60,

    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    RequireConsent = false,
},
```

And my angular configuration is as follows

```
  import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

  export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    // Url of the Identity Provider
    issuer: 'https://localhost:44300',

    // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/checkout" ,

    clientId: 'angularClient',


    responseType: 'code',

    scope: 'openid api1.read',

    showDebugInformation: true,
  };
```

For testing maybe it would be great to test it with two minutes to see if the user will be redirected back to the login page?

Comment: Not really what you requested, but did you think about the silent-refresh approach? https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/master/docs-src/silent-refresh.md

Comment: I came across this but was not quite sure if this does the job. Is there anything that has to be changed from my ID server side? based on the above configuration

Comment: Yes, you would need to register a second redirect url (silentRefreshRedirectUri) for the silent refresh page. I also implemented the silent refresh once, it worked very well without the user noticing anything

Comment: ok understood. But in my usecase I have a small application and I would like to be redirected back to the login page (user noticing) when the token expires for example. I think the silent refresh works the other way round.

Comment: I guess it is then only possible by a timer (needs to defined globally somehow) /a guard (only on route change)/an interceptor (when request failed with 401)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `UserSsoLifetime` for the client

> The maximum duration (in seconds) since the last time the user authenticated. Defaults to null. You can adjust the lifetime of a session token to control when and how often a user is required to reenter credentials instead of being silently authenticated, when using a web application.

Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/client.html?highlight=client#authentication-logout)